# audio player for Asp.net Website

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

How do i embed audio player for website in asp.net Webforms,i have stored the File name in SQL database and files stored in Folder .how do i Embed that audio files dynamically and which Audio player plugins is suitable .i have to show like a list and Play.

i'm using

Visual Studio 2008,
Sql server 2008 R2

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your required browser support, you may be able to get away with simply using the html5 [`<audio>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video) tag.

All you'd need to do is render your list from the database (asp:Repeater perhaps?) with each entry having its own `<audio>` tag pointing at the appropriate file.